# Debugging Friggeri's CV - Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)

Tags: boxes, badness, friggeri-cv

I am trying to debug my CV made using [Friggeri's CV template](https://github.com/afriggeri/cv) but there is still a recurrent warning I cannot get rid of no matter what I try...

I am using the same friggeri-cv.cls file, I have only changed all the Helvetica fonts to Arial and added "backend=biber" to the "\RequirePackage{biblatex}" line.

The warning I cannot get rid of is an "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)" that appears every time I use the "entrylist" environment, being the relevant lines in the friggeri-cv.cls file the following:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% List environment %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{11.8cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

Please find below a MWE that can reproduce the warning. Many thanks!

```
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}

\begin{document}
\header{name}{surname}
       {occupation}

% In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\begin{aside}
  \section{about}
    aaa
    bbb
\end{aside}

\section{background}

\begin{entrylist}
  \entry
    {1991}
    {MSc {\normalfont in this and that}}
    {This institution}
    {{\thinfont Specialized in this and that}\\
    Honorary Mention}
  \entry
    {1993}
    {PhD {\normalfont in other stuff}}
    {This institution}
    {{\thinfont Specialized in other stuff}\\
    Honorary Mention}
\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem, as you detected, is on the definition of the `entrylist` environment; it's solved by letting the environment end the previous paragraph before the `tabular*` material and also to end the paragraph after the `tabular*`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \par\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}\par
}  
\makeatother
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \par\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}\par
}  
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\header{name}{surname}
       {occupation}

% In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\begin{aside}
  \section{about}
    aaa
    bbb
\end{aside}

\section{background}

\begin{entrylist}
  \entry
    {1991}
    {MSc {\normalfont in this and that}}
    {This institution}
    {{\thinfont Specialized in this and that}\\
    Honorary Mention}
  \entry
    {1993}
    {PhD {\normalfont in other stuff}}
    {This institution}
    {{\thinfont Specialized in other stuff}\\
    Honorary Mention}
\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Makes sense! And works perfectly! Thanks Gonzalo!